# how does a client know where a WCF endpoint is when it calls a windows azure WCF service

Tags: azure

for ex you have:
2 instances of a worker role, 2 instances of a web role.

the worker role calls a WCF service on the web role. If I have only one web role, it knows it's addressand all is fine. But if I have 2 web roles, how do they accomplish load ballance, how does the worker role know which instance of the web role to call to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load balancing in general works by having a separate piece of hardware that acts as the designated target for the service that is being balanced. As each new request arrives it is then simply forwarded to one of the actual target machines that provide this service implementation.

In your particular case the load balancer will be the single public endpoint for your web roles. DNS lookups or direct IP addressing will result in requests arriving at the load balancer machine and not directly to any of the web roles. The balancer then forwards the request to one of the two web role instances that are known by the load balancer.

One of the advantages of this approach is that you can quickly start new web role instances if you anticipate a spike in traffic. All Azure needs to do is inform the load balancer those new instances are available and they will immediately start accepting new requests. Likewise you can scale back the number of instances. Because the load balancer itself is not being restarted it means your service is not disrupted.

You can find more detailed information at...

[Cisco Definition](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094820.shtml)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29)

[DevCentral](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/dmacvittie/archive/2009/03/17/intro-to-load-balancing-for-developers-ndash-how-they-work.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure load balances Web Roles automatically, you don't have to do anything.

If you *need* to address specific web role instances, I would suggest you reconsider your architecture, specifically look at using shared state via the SQL Server session state provider, or look at the appfabric cache provider in the training kit labs.

Comment: this is true if I use queues. But is it possible to do this using wcf? Thanks for your answare